# Have I changed the intent of the overridden `==` operator?

Tags: c#, null, operator-overloading

The following overloaded `==`operator is part of the `Calender` class in [QL.net](http://sourceforge.net/projects/qlnet/)

```
    public static bool operator ==(Calendar c1, Calendar c2)
    {
        return (c1.empty() && c2.empty()) 
                || (!c1.empty() && !c2.empty() && c1.name() == c2.name());
    }

    public bool empty() { return (object)calendar == null; }
```

When I try to access the `SouthAfricanCalender` property, I receive a `System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` which prompted me to dig into the source.

```
public SouthAfrica SouthAfricanCalender
{
    get
    {
        if (_calender == null)
        {
        _calender = new SouthAfrica();
        }
    return _calender;
    }
    set
    {
        if (_calender == null)
        { 
        _calender = value;
        }
    }
}

SouthAfrica _calender;
```

I have ammended the overload as follows based on the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155458/c-object-is-not-null-but-myobject-null-still-return-false)

```
public static bool operator ==(Calendar c1, Calendar c2)
{
   if ( object.ReferenceEquals(c1,c2)) return true;
   if ((object)c1 == null || (object)c2 == null) return false;

   return (c1.empty() && c2.empty())
       || (!c1.empty() && !c2.empty() && c1.name() == c2.name());
}
```

My question, have I changed the intent of the original code with my amendment?

Edit: any suggestions on how this can be cleaned up further?

Comment: You dont need `if ((object)c1 == null || (object)c2 == null) return false;` no casting to object required. only `if c1 == null || (c2 == null) return false;`

Comment: @aliostad: Not true! Without the cast to `object` you'll potentially get an infinite loop of `==` calls leading to a `StackOverflowException`.

Comment: In your updated == method, after the first two if statements, you've already determined that both c1 and c2 are non-null. You can change your return statement to `return c1.name() == c2.name();`

Comment: @david - i was thinking the same - just need to make sure that nothing weird happening in the `name()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You ensure that both are objects, and respond accordingly in the places that they aren't (assuming that ReferenceEquals can handle double null). Then you simply execute the same check. The whole .empty() thing is totally unnecessary, by the way, you already know that it's not null, just return the name comparison.

Answer (score 1):

No, you haven't.

It still checks for equality.