# Does it make a difference to check null on either side of conditional?

Tags: c#, oop

I have seen both

```
if(something == null)
```

and

```
if(null == something)
```

Does it make a difference in which order this null check happens?  I do not see a difference in functionality but would love to know if there is reasoning behind it.

Comment: It's like 2 == 3 and 3 == 2, the side do not affect the outcome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is legal in C# and is colloquially known as a [Yoda Condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7013263/difference-between-null-x-and-x-null/7013280#7013280). Many people in the C/C++ world like this because it guards at compile time against replacing `==` with `=` by accident. However, it has fallen out of favor in C# due to the fact the compiler will flag it (the single `=`) as an error in that instance (so long as it's not a `boolean` eval).

Comment: I prefer this syntax, but I could see why people find it confusing. I just hate when I see this:

     if(true == myVariable)
     {

     }

Answer (score 5):

Some programmers prefer to put the constant on the left side of an equality operator to avoid accidents (a typo of `=` instead of `==`).  In the second example, having the `=` typo would introduce a compiler error, which is easy to fix, whereas in the first example such a typo may introduce a bug that is very difficult to find.

This practice comes directly out of C and C++ programming style.  I don't know whether it would affect C#.  If it's no longer relevant, then it's more likely to be a habit rather than a strategy.