# c# Strange result on compare operation

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a strange behavior on my c# code (asp.net code behind). I post here a screenshot of the watch window:

[image: strange null comparation result]

I have an object user that is null (as you can see) and the compare: user == null returns false. I don't understand why!

Is someone here that can explain why this happens?

Comment: Can you add a watch on `user.ToString()`? Also, do you have access to the code for the declared type of `user`?

Comment: Have you tried null == user ?

Comment: Have you overloaded the == operator on user? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/155458/c-sharp-object-is-not-null-but-myobject-null-still-return-false

Comment: I think @StriplingWarrior may be onto the answer - user is not null, but the ToString function (for some reason) returns null given the current value of user.

Comment: Navigate to the variable and show what it is, if it a propery,show what is the code in the getter, also check if comparision operators are overloaded for this class

Comment: Are you a psychologist testing the reaction of deterministic minded people in the face of paradox? :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well you can easily write your own class which would give that result:

```
public class Evil
{
    public static bool operator ==(Evil lhs, Evil rhs)
    {
        return false;
    }

    public static bool operator !=(Evil lhs, Evil rhs)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

We're only guessing, at the moment... but that explains the symptoms.

(I've just tried overriding ToString, and I can't get the desired output.)

Comment: @Daniel: It's an example of what could show the given output.

Comment: I think `return null` is more likely in the `ToString()` implementation. `return "null"` would cause the quotes to be displayed in the debugger.

Comment: It's just speculation as to why such a comparison would return null in one case, but false in the null check.

Comment: It have been long time i used Wathc in VS but the string would be `"null"`?

Comment: Curious, how does the static Object.Equals(object, object) behave in this case?  Could it be used to test for the presence of Evil?

Comment: @AaronAnodide Perhaps `Object.ReferenceEquals` as the `Evil` object could still override the `Equals` implementation. EDIT: Sorry, misread. Not sure if `Object.Equals` calls the virtual `Equals` method or not on the object.

Comment: @AaronAnodide: `object.Equals(((Evil)null), null)` behaves correctly with this `Evil` class. It has no actual instance to call `.Equals()` on, so it returns true after determining that both objects are null. (It could still cause incorrect behavior if you compared `object.Equals(new Evil(), null)` if you override the `.Equals()` method in the Evil class, though.

Comment: @StriplingWarriorm why shouldnt be, typicaly you compare reference if they are falce then you go for equal(). Probably if operator for == would return always true then the object.Equal(object,object) will fail.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior, What is the product of `typeOf((Evil)null)` ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Someone in my team did an override definition for the == operator and i didn't think to check it and there was the error.  You helped me a lot!

Comment: @Vash: I don't think `typeof((Evil)null)` is valid code; you need to provide a compile-time type reference, not an object instance. Maybe you're thinking of `((Evil)null).GetType()`? (which would throw a `NullReferenceException` of course)