# Comparing null values in LINQ expressions

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, null

I have a table with a “`t_cftc_ir_swaps`” with following fields

```
T_CFTC_IR_SWAP_ID       Integer (Autonumber, PK)
PRODUCT                 Varchar
TRADEVOLUME_TYPE        Varchar
TRADEVOLUME_BUCKET_1    Varchar
TRADEVOLUME_BUCKET_2    Varchar
TRADEVOLUME_GROUP       Varchar
TRADEVOLUME             Integer
RELEASE_DATE            Date
TRADE_DATE              Date
```

I am using Entity Framework at the code level. I am trying to insert a record into this table. But before doing that I am checking if the record already exists in the table. For that purpose I have a “RecordAlreadyExists” function code as follows

[image: Record already exists function]

Now in some of the records in the data table we have null values for “TRADEVOLUME_BUCKET_2” but while inserting a new record if I try to compare the record being added (with a null value for TRADEVOLUME_BUCKET_2) against the underlying table records it returns “0” records even though I can query the database and see there are matching records in the table.

At the code break this is the record I am trying to insert. As you can see it has null value for “TRADEVOLUME_BUCKET_2”

[image: Code at runtime]

The count of records matching with the records which we are trying to add is “0”

[image]

When I run a query at the database level I do get a matching record already in the underlying table

[image: data query]
[image: query result]

I have even tries using DBNull at code as follows

[image: use of db null]

But get the following exception when I try to do that at runtime
“Unable to create a null constant value of type ‘System.Object’. Only entity types, enumeration types or primitive types are supported in this context”

[image: db null exception]

How should I compare null values using LINQ query?

Comment: What query does EF send to the database?

Comment: Which version of EF are you using?

Comment: @GertArnold - EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0

Comment: @RobH - - Undelrying query is a select query on all records and doesn't show the where clause.

SELECT 
"Extent1"."T_CFTC_IR_SWAPS_ID" AS "T_CFTC_IR_SWAPS_ID", 
"Extent1"."PRODUCT" AS "PRODUCT", 
"Extent1"."TRADEVOLUME_TYPE" AS "TRADEVOLUME_TYPE", 
"Extent1"."TRADEVOLUME_BUCKET_1" AS "TRADEVOLUME_BUCKET_1", 
"Extent1"."TRADEVOLUME_BUCKET_2" AS "TRADEVOLUME_BUCKET_2", 
"Extent1"."TRADEVOLUME_GROUP" AS "TRADEVOLUME_GROUP", 
"Extent1"."TRADEVOLUME" AS "TRADEVOLUME", 
"Extent1"."RELEASE_DATE" AS "RELEASE_DATE", 
"Extent1"."TRADE_DATE" AS "TRADE_DATE"
FROM "CLOUDDBA"."T_CFTC_IR_SWAPS" "Extent1"

Comment: Is this the query that comes from the `Count` statement?

Comment: @GertArnold - Thats the query I can see in the Autos section in visual studio when I put a break on the code line

intExistingCount =
                    CftcContext.T_CFTC_IR_SWAPS.Count(
                        rec => (object)rec.TRADEVOLUME_BUCKET_2 == ((object)_record.TRADEVOLUME_BUCKET_2 ?? DBNull.Value)
                    );

So it does show the entire record set on which the query is going to be applied on but doesn't show the where clause conditions which I am adding on top of it

Comment: That's only the ToString of the DbSet object. Now please monitor the query as it is sent to the database. It should be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking for `null` specifically:

```
public bool RecordAlreadyExists(object cftcRecord)
{
    var _intExistingCount = 0;
    var _record = cftcRecord as T_CFTC_IR_SWAPS;
    if (_record != null)
    {
        _intExistingCount = 
        CftcContext.T_CFTC_IR_SWAPS.Count(
            rec => _record.TRADEVOLUME_BUCKET_2 == null 
                    ? rec.TRADEVOLUME_BUCKET_2 == null 
                    : _record.TRADEVOLUME_BUCKET_2 == rec.TRADEVOLUME_BUCKET_2
            );
    }
    // More code...
}
```

I've changed your code slightly (it's better to include code in your question as *text* so answerers can copy it). I think this is the problem you are encountering: http://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-ado-net-entity-framework-ef-feature-suggestions/suggestions/1015361-incorrect-handling-of-null-variables-in-where-cl

Answer (score 1):

Try giving a default value, to your property. I think you are facing a problem of NULL not being compared in Linq ... but default values such as an empty string is.

Check out these links

- [Checking if an object is null in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6417902/checking-if-object-is-null-in-c-sharp)
- [C# object is not null but (myObject != null) still return false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155458/c-sharp-object-is-not-null-but-myobject-null-still-return-false)

Answer (score -1):

Use the null coalescing operator on something other than DBNull.Value.